# How does an email whose "Original-Recipient" field that does not match the "To" know how to find my inbox?

Tags: email

I receive lots of junk mail where the "To" header field is a bogus email address (for example acmotzb98cig@icloud.com), while the header field "Original-Recipient" does contain my email address (with the iCloud domain).

It seems like the iCloud email server is ignoring the "To" field and using the "Original-Recipient" as the real target email address.

Apple's DMARC profile quarantines this kind of email and delivers them to my Junk mail folder. The problem with this DMARC profile is that my Junk mail folder receives tons of junk making it difficult to sort through them and find legitimate emails that have mistakenly found their way into my Junk folder.

I am trying to find a way to automatically delete all emails that have a bogus "To" header field and or fail Apple's DMARC policy.